# Unable to style paper-drawer-panel in Polymer 1.0 using Custom CSS Mixins

Tags: css, polymer, mixins

I am trying to style the paper-drawer-panel using the Custom CSS Mixins as mentioned [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-css-mixins). The paper-drawer-panel.css file applies

```
@apply(--paper-drawer-panel-left-drawer-container);
@apply(--paper-drawer-panel-main-container);
```

respectively for the drawer and the main containers. But, the styles set using the mixins do not seem to be working
The below is the code for paper-drawer-panel demo I have used.

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>paper-drawer-panel demo</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/paper-styles/demo.css">

        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">

        <style>
        #drawerPanel {
        --paper-drawer-panel-left-drawer-container: {
          background-color: #eee;
        };
        --paper-drawer-panel-main-container: {
          background-color: gray;
        };
      }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body class="unresolved fullbleed">

        <paper-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
        <div drawer> 
            <div>Drawer content... </div>
        </div>
        <div main>
            <div>
              <paper-button paper-drawer-toggle raised>toggle drawer</paper-button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </paper-drawer-panel>
      </body>
</html>
```

The documentation over at https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel states that this is valid too.

> Styling paper-drawer-panel:
>
> To change the main container: paper-drawer-panel {
>   --paper-drawer-panel-main-container: { background-color: gray; }; }
>
> To change the drawer container when it's in the left side:
>   paper-drawer-panel { --paper-drawer-panel-left-drawer-container: {
>   background-color: white; }; }

So, what am I doing wrong in trying to get this simple thing working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am also testing the new styling schema of Polymer 1.0. It seems that you need to add `is="custom-style"` to the style tag.

Comment: That seems to have worked. The demo explained in the documentation doesn't use the `is="custom-style"` though. Maybe that is if we are styling an element's local dom inside another element. I need to test more I guess.

Comment: Yeah, it's outside of the element. I found a [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-style) that might be useful

Comment: Before 1.0 you had to add "shim-shadow" like <style shim-shadow>... now its <style is="custom-style">... I guess that would be a breaking change for anyone converting over to 1.0.0